# Como fazer o <p:editor> do primefaces escapar os caracteres especiais digitados pelo usuário antes de gravá-los?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou usando o componente  do primefaces. Meu problema é que ele está gravando os acentos que o usuário digita no texto sem fazer o devido *escaping* HTML. Tem como mudar isso para ele saber que a letra é um acento e precisar realizar o devido *escaping* HTML?

Abaixo segue o código:

```xml
<p:editor id="corpoEmail" widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{corpoEmailControl.corpoEmail}" width="700"  maxlength="2000"  />
```

Comment: Você sabe que nem tudo o que o usuário pode digitar está na tabela ASCII, né? Tem certeza que você não quis dizer UTF-8 ou Unicode?

Comment: eu gostaria que em vez de ele gravar o acento grava o código asciii. Exemplo: o usuário digita gás e ele grava g&aacute;s
Eu vou usar esse texto para enviar um e-mail, se eu deixar o acento o browser da pessoa que receber esse e-mail não vai reconhecer o acento.

Comment: Ou seja o que você quer que ele grave `g&acute;s` ao invés de `gás`?

Comment: Sim, como eu falei esse texto vai ser enviado no corpo do e-mail.

Comment: Ok, mas neste caso há de se convir que o que você quer é escapar os caracteres que não estão na tabela ASCII/ANSI de 7 bits. Isso é algo muito diferente de "não gravar o código ASCII".

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro, espero que concorde com a minha edição.

Comment: Ok. Só espero que consigo a resposta. Estou procurando na internet.

Comment: Estou pensando em dar replace na string em todos os acentos possíveis.

Comment: Pessoal eu acabei usando essa classe StringEscapeUtils o problema que ela converte tudo até tags do html.

Comment: @RenatoRomão, seria interessante postar como resposta como solucionou o problema

Answer (score 1):

No momento de salvar o campo para o banco de dados, use o [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) da [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

// ...

String corpoEmailEscapado = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(corpoEmail);
```